# Rails date_select undefined method string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need some help here,

I'm using the `date_select` helper from Rails in a form to get a date in the format `%d/%m/%Y`. The helper seems to work fine in development but it doesn't in test mode.

In test mode, I got failure/error when a failed POST is made and the test needs to re-render the view. I got the follow failure/error message:

```
Failure/Error: <%= f.date_select :birthdate,

ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `year' for "{3=>15, 2=>6, 1=>2001}":String
```

or, depending on how I format the date

```
ActionView::Template::Error:   
   undefined method `year' for "15/06/2001":String
```

It only happens with failed posts (when is needed to re-render the form), both for rspec `request` and `feature` tests. In development mode, it works fine to re-render de form.

My tests

```
# feature test 
it "sign up with false credential" do
  users = FactoryBot.attributes_for(:users)

  visit 'users/sign_up'
  fill_in 'user_name', :with => "test"
  find_by_id('user_birthdate_3i').find("option[value='15']").select_option
  find_by_id('user_birthdate_2i').find("option[value='6']").select_option
  find_by_id('user_birthdate_1i').find("option[value='2001']").select_option

  click_button('Save')
  expect(page).to have_selector "#error_explanation"
end
```

And

```
# request test
it "signs usuario_candidato up with wrong attributes" do
  users = FactoryBot.attributes_for(:users)
  expect{ post user_registration_path,
    :params => {
      "user" => {
        "name" => user[:name],
        "birthdate" => "2018/12/31"
      }
    }
  }.to change{ User.count }.by(0)
end
```

The form

```
<%= f.date_select :birthdate,
  options = {
    start_year: Date.current.year,
    end_year: 1950,
    order: [:day, :month, :year],
    prompt: { day: 'day', month: 'month', year: 'year' }
  }
%>
```

Some observations:

- The same test format works for feature and request when the is a
  successful post.
- I'm using locale PT-BR, with default format to %d/%m/Y%
- I'm using Postgres, with `birthdate` as Date type.
- I'm using Devise controller to this form, and I didn't override the controller's actions.
- As I already said, development mode don't reproduce this error.
- I already try different date format (e.g %m/%d%/%Y or year/month/day) before posting, it always return the same error. Because of that, my suggestion to the problem is: after the post fails, the return is a String when it should be a Date class.

Anyone already face this problem?
Any additional information, just ask on comments.
Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE

After 6 days of posting, I was trying a suggestion someone gave on comments, and it happens that the tests passed, no error was raised. I didn't make the suggestion, I just change from a `text_field` to the `date_field` (as I wasn't able to use `date_field`, I changed to `text_field` and moved on to the next problem).

I found a certain inconsistency at how Rails works with date. Before the first raise of the problem, it was passing the tests normally. Then the error happened, now it's not happen anymore.

I have similar problem with a Regex that I use in my model for validate dates:

Model

```
# dd/mm/yyyy
VALID_DATE = /\A[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\z/

validates :birthdate, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_DATE, message: "must be in the format DD/MM/YYYY" }
```

When I create the validation, it works fine. Values in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` used not pass in model tests. In the next day, Rspec started to raise errors saying that `yyyy-mm-dd` and others should be valid (therefore, ignoring the regex validation)

Model test error

```
User birthdate should be invalid
 Failure/Error: expect(user).to_not be_valid
  expected #<User id: nil, name: "Sra. Margarida Sophie Santana", birthdate: "2000-12-29", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> not to be valid
```

The only thing I have extra for date is a date_formats.rb in config/initializer with the follow value:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y"
```

I have it for a long time.

Apparently Rails changes when it decides to transform string values in date values (when it was passing the regex validation test, it was passing the date as string, when the problem raise up the date was been transformed from string to date before the validation).

Comment: I think the date value in the html should be in yyyy-mm-dd format, have you tried that? If that doesn't work: Are both test failing? can you post the controller code where it actually fails?

Comment: but with `-`? so `"2018-12-31"`?

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez: undefined method `year' for "2018-12-31":String

Comment: The weirds thing is, in the feature test, I just select the value in the select_option with Javascript, I didn't change the request in any way. But it still fails, while, in development mode, it doesn't. It must be in the way it assigns value to fields after a post fails, the mode dev. must be different in the way the mode test do.

Comment: why does the request spec fail?  that isn't using any form right?

Comment: @Anthony - The reason it's failing I posted in the question, also post the tests. About using a "form", I believe requests tests uses the whole rails stack (view, controllers, models). Controllers tests seems to use only controllers.

Comment: Try "birthdate" => Date.parse("2018/12/31")

Comment: And make sure that you have javascript enabled for feature specs